# couchdb date format automatically updated

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb, javascriptserializer, jsonserializer

Whenever I update any key in couchdb document, it updates existing all date keys in milliseconds formats.

Example:

```
created_at: 2013-07-09T09:25:00
```

to

```
created_at: /Date(1373354700000)/
```

do you ever come across this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of this conversion can be find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_sidebarb).

If you're using `JavaScriptSerializer` then it converts the `DateTime` object as the format

> /Date(ticks)/

But It will not convert `DateTime` string to ticks.

Whereas, if you're using JsonSerializer then you will find the date and time in correct format no matter of object or string type.

Note: `JavaScriptSerializer` is too slow in as compared to `JsonConvert`. You can have [performance comparison](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/01/01/net-serialization-performance-comparison) of different serialization.